# Filtering values in ggplot2?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, filter

Update:
I finally figured out how to do the plotting. The code below works for me:

```
mydf %>%
  dplyr::filter(NAME =="" & GENDER =="") %>%
  ggplot(aes(YEAR, RANK)) +
  geom_point()
```

Now I am working on converting it into a function that will take name and gender as arguments. The function is case sensitive and should still display a plot if the gender argument is missing. Here is my progress so far with the function. It is displaying a plot with two arguments, but if I remove the gender argument, it displays a blank plot. Do I need to apply the grep or grepl inside my function? Thanks everyone!

```
 name.plot <- function(name="", gender="", ignore.case=TRUE){ 
  mydf %>% 
  dplyr::filter(NAME == name & GENDER == gender) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(YEAR, RANK)) + 
  geom_point()  
}
```

> I am working on my homework and need some help. We were given a
>   dataset of babynames and supposed to write a function that will take a
>   name and a gender and returns a plot of rank against year.
>
> Currently, I'm figuring out how to display the plot first. I figured
>   out how to display a name, but when I tried to add gender, it's just
>   giving me a blank plot. Can someone please help me what I am doing
>   wrong? I tried both group by and which functions, but no luck.

```
p1 <- mydf %>%
  filter(NAME =="Madison", GENDER =="girl") %>%
  ggplot(aes(YEAR, RANK)) +
  geom_point()
p1
```

Here is my sample dataset:

[image: Babynames 1880-2008]

Comment: I guess you would fare better to separate your data in a more programmatic way. Meaning use facets and aesthetics for grouping. E.g, use `+ geom_point(data = mydf, aes(YEAR, RANK, color = NAME)) + facet_grid(˜GENDER)`  (apologies for the weird tilda sign - using a weird keyboard atm)

Comment: Not sure how it works. Right now, I'm just figuring out to display a plot and later on I will have to create a function that will take name and gender as arguments and display a plot.

Comment: Have you tried my code? Replace the weird tilda with a normal tilda sign, and add it to your p

Comment: `@Tjebo`, I did and still not working :(

Comment: There seems to be something peculiar going on with your data .... John, WIlliam and James first ranked for girl  names in 1880 ?

Comment: `@Tjebo` thanks for pointing it out, will have to figure out why it does it when I read the CSV file. I added a sample dataset from the actual CSV file.

Comment: Please read this thread here how to make data and better questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I think I finally figured out how to plot, but how do I put it into a function that will take the name and gender as arguments?

Comment: You are using the `filter` function improperly.  You need to include a logical test (& or |) between your two filter statements like: `df %>% filter( NAME =="John" & GENDER =="boy")`

Comment: `@Dave2e`, Thank you, but I finally figured out that part. Now I'm stuck on how to put into a function that will take name and gender as arguments. If there are no matches, the function should still display an empty plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  I should point out that often the `filter()` function you want to call, `dplyr::filter()`, is often conflicting with the `stats::filter()` function.  I usually explicitly call using `dplyr::filter()` for that reason (rather than using `filter()` alone).

Secondly, you can also pull out data to filter using `subset(df, ...)` within the data argument of any ggplot function.  So the code below should work to show you what you need:

```
ggplot(df, aes(YEAR, RANK)) +
    geom_point(data=subset(df, NAME=='Madison' & GENDER=='girl'))
```

Comment: I tried both of these and still not working :( It would display a plot for the first input, but if I tried a different name or gender, it was still giving me a blank plot.

Comment: Hard to give better direction without checking the actual data - can you post the dataset?  (use R syntax like `data.frame(NAME=c(...), GENDER=c(...),...)` to make it easier to help you).

Comment: Oh - and note that you would have to change the code I have so that `df` is your actual dataframe name.  If it's `mydf`, then use that in both places.

Comment: I did that, I changed it to my actual data frame which is mydf. The same issues I have with my current code. It will display the first input name, but if I tried something else, it would give me a blank plot.

Comment: I think I finally figured out how to plot, but how do I put it into a function that will take the name and gender as arguments?

Comment: Sure - I would update your post to indicate what worked for you to plot it (give the code and the output would be helpful for us and others who find it in the future).  Also - is your function taking strings as input or variables?  I ask because `aes()` takes variable names as input, but for functions you often pass character strings, so you would use `aes_string()` in the calls to `ggplot`.  Check the documentation on `aes_string()` to see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210186/discussion-between-pinaypy-and-chemdork123).